# Generating sublists from a list with complexity less than O(n2)

Tags: java, collections, time-complexity

```
HashSet<String> result=new HashSet();
String str ="";
for (Iterator iter = xyz.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    str = // get some String property of the object 
    result.add(str);
}
List list = null ;
for(String s : result){
    list = new ArrayList();
    for (Iterator iter1 = xyz.iterator(); iter1.hasNext();) {
        if(s.contains(//String property of the object){
            list.add();
        }
    }
    //do something with the list
}
```

xyz is a list of objects.
Here, i am grouping a list of objects based on a particular property.
The code takes long time in worst case scenario. Is it possible to make this code smaller and less complex ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: It's a bit hard (at least for me) to understand this question. Could you share an example input and the output you're trying to get for that input?

Comment: Is `// get some String property of the object` and `//String property of the object` the same property? Perhaps you want to run `result.contains` and not `s.contains`. Then you wouldn't need to iterate over the elements of the Set.

Comment: Can't you do it inline? Instead of adding it to set first and then iterating over set, you can iterate through list directly and calculate if it contains a string and add it there only.?

Comment: yes both are same ..@Eran

Comment: Are you doing grouping? If yes there are good apis in Java 8 Streams for it. https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/

Comment: I got it @eran .. but will it make my code any better in terms of complexity.?.

Comment: Thanks @SubirKumarSao...  i am looking it .

Comment: @Akhilesh Yes, it will make it O(n).

Comment: @JimGarrison this would not be good for Code Review as it is stripped of context and mostly example code, which is not meaningfully reviewable. That said, if the OP wish to post their __real, working__ code, without leaving out parts of it, it could be good for CR.